# Can't find a CSS margin to remove it

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to remove the margin in the screenshot attached (see http://goo.gl/tbw4V), but I can't for the life of me see where it is in my WordPress stylesheet to remove it! I was hoping someone on hear could possibly help me? I have checked the H1, H2 tags, .bylines DIV and paragraph tags but nothing seems to be pushing the entry information approximately 15 pixels below the header. My website is at http://gracefulpostcards.com

Thanks for any help,

Steven.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To adjust these styles is highly recommended that you use the **Firebug** extension for Chrome or Firefox. So you can debug the html page and styles.

In your case, simply set the property `margin-bottom` of selector `.singular .entry-title` with 0:

```
.singular .entry-title {
margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this worked perfectly. I had to insert it in the last line before my head tag closed because inserting into the stylesheet wouldn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

in style.css line 753

```
.hentry .entry-title {
    margin: 0 0 0.6em 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.featured {
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Is the CSS rule you have to change.

If this is the page you are talking about : http://gracefulpostcards.com/why-start-a-personal-blog/#.UKGMi4csDng

then removing this CSS rule deletes the margin-bottom perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Look in style.css, the style starting at line 753.

How I found it? Google Chrome -> Right click -> Inspect element.

Answer (score 0):

The margin is defined under the selector `.hentry .entry-title`. It's `margin: 0 0 0.6em 0`. Just make it 0.

Answer (score -1):

After inspecting your page, it seems that h2.entry-title has a margin-bottom

To fix this, add the following to your css:

`h2 {
   margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}`